# "Using OS scope before setting MAKEFILE_GENERATOR" in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have downloaded and installed Qt and I'm learning how to use it.
So, I created a new project `myfristqt` (empty project). I then added a `main.cpp` file with this code:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

First thing I noticed `#include <QApplication>` line is hightlighted with a red line as if `QApplication` was an unknown identifier. So, I compiled it to see what happens and here's the error I got:

```
(internal):1: error : Using OS scope before setting MAKEFILE_GENERATOR
```

Any idea why this is happening ? I'm using Windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MAKEFILE_GENERATOR** is a qmake variable.

This variable contains the name of the Makefile generator to use when generating a Makefile. The value of this variable is typically handled internally by qmake and rarely needs to be modified.

It define in QTDIR/mkspecs/PLATFORM/qmake.conf. Where PLATFORM is maybe cygwin-g++, win32-msvc200x on your Windows XP.